# How to receive callbacks on network loss for Android Nougat when app is closed?

Tags: android, networking, broadcastreceiver, android-networking, android-7.0-nougat

I want to be able to have any network change or any loss of network connectivity wake my app's bound Service when the app is closed. This used to be accomplished by listening for the CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE broadcasts before doing so was deprecated in Android Nougat. One may still listen to these broadcasts only while the app is open by programmatically creating a broadcast receiver, but my app also needs to be woken if it is closed.

I noticed the ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(NetworkRequest, PendingIntent) method and its JavaDoc claims that it works while the app is closed, but when I call it from my Service, it seems to only work a single time before it stops responding to events. I see similar problems with ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(NetworkRequest, NetworkCallback), a Lollipop function that only works with the app open. How do I get this PendingIntent-based callback to work consistently?

All of the replacements Google suggests in place of CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE broadcasts merely check for the presence of a network. Most of them are job scheduling services. They assume CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE broadcasts were only being used to wait for network availability to perform a job. However, my app is a VPN network utility, so I need to be notified on any network change-- I'm not merely awaiting the presence of a network.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your service implement the [NetworkCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback) interface and on the **onCreate** or **onStartCommand** of the Service register your callback/service using the [registerNetworkCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#registerNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)) and unregister on the  **onDestroy**.

In the callbacks such as **onAvailable** or **onLost**, you add your business logic.

Comment: As I mentioned, this does not appear to work reliably when the app is closed. Perhaps turning off battery optimization is the right answer, but I already tried this answer in the question.

Comment: I see, didn't realise that you want to fire up your service when there is a connectivity change. Check out this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization#connectivity-action) from the official docs that says how to achieve that. TLDR: Schedule a jobs with the **[setRequiredNetworkType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setRequiredNetworkType(int))**